# Why is the modal dialog in MFC actually internally modeless?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

This question arose in my miind after reading this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3911/The-singular-non-modality-of-MFC-modal-dialogs. He mentions that the modal dialog in MFC is not strictly modal, but implemented as a modeless dialog(internally) with bells and whistles to make it behave as a modal one.

Specifically, he says:

> The MFC command routing mechanism uses a combination of message maps
>   and virtual functions to achieve what it does and a true modal dialog
>   will totally wreck this mechanism because then the modal message loop
>   is controlled outside the scope of the MFC command routing machinery

Could anyone elucidate this statement? An example of what would have gone wrong if they had tried to implement a truly modal dialog would greatly clear things up.

Answer (score 2):

A modal dialog stops your message loop, but there must still be a message loop to handle the events for the dialog. So a modal dialog simply a non-modal dialog with its own internal message loop.